# Geos installation in non-standard location

Tags: ruby, compilation, rubygems, nitrousio, rgeo

I'm running on [nitrous.io](https://www.nitrous.io/) and trying to install the [rgeo](https://github.com/dazuma/rgeo) gem using ruby 2.0.0-p353.

I don't have `sudo` access, so I tried to compile and install [geos](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) from source.

Once I downloaded and untarred the source files, I `cd` into the source folder and run

```
mkdir /home/action/local && ./configure --prefix=/home/action/local
make && make install
```

This runs for a bit.  I then run

```
gem install rgeo -- --with-geos-dir=/home/action/local
```

Things look alright, but if I hop into a terminal I get

```
RGeo::Geos.supported?
> false
```

Looking back over the `mkmf.log` file, I see these lines:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgeos                                                                                                                                                    
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgeos_c                                                                                                                                                  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgeos                                                                                                                                                    
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgeos_c
```

This blog post: http://blog.thefrontiergroup.com.au/page/2/ mentions creating symbolic links to fix this issue:

```
cd /usr/lib
sudo ln -s libgeos-3.3.3.so libgeos.so
sudo ln -s libgeos-3.3.3.so libgeos.so.1
```

`libgeos` isn't installed to usr/lib for me, it's in `/home/action/local/lib` and when I check that directory I see `libgeos.so` is already symlinked to `libgeos-x.x.x.so`.

If I switch ruby versions to 1.9.3-p392 and run the gem installation line, everything works as planned.

On my MacBook Pro I can successfully use `rgeo` with `ruby 2.0.0-p395`, but the geos library is installed by [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and therefore in a path `rgeo` is expecting.

Was there a change with ruby 2.0 that affects compiling gems?

I'm using RVM on all machines

Comment: If only non-standard spellings of non-standard were standard :).  Thanks for the catch