# Installing pyspatialite fails on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pyspatialite

```
pip install pyspatialite==2.6.2-spatialite.2.4.0-4
```

Fails on Ubuntu with the error:

```
__main__.HeaderNotFoundException: cannot find proj_api.h, bailing out
```

Doing

```
sudo apt-get install libproj-dev libgeos-3.4.2 libgeos-dev
```

turns this error into

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgeos
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libgeos-3.4.2
```

reveals that libgeos-3.4.2 was "manually installed" on my Ubuntu instance.  This is fixed by:

```
sudo apt-get purge libgeos-3.4.2
sudo apt-get install libgeos-3.4.2 libgeos-dev
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libgeos-3.4.2.so /usr/lib/libgeos.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libgeos-3.4.2.so /usr/lib/libgeos.so.1
```

(See [Geos installation in non-standard location](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21557845/2800876) for why the last two lines are needed)